# Where can I find a table of ocean temperature pressure and depth

Tags: ocean, temperature

What type of data is available for ocean depth and density?  For instance, are there measurements of density near Greenland or Antarctica that could be compared to the central Pacific?  It would be nice to have temperature and salinity measurements to go along with the density values.  Also, how deep and how often are measurements made of density as a function of depth in the ocean?

Comment: Any particular ocean?

Comment: The original question was definitely more relevant. A general average condition for the global ocean is based on probably too many assumptions.

Comment: Giving an example of atmospheric data does not clarify the request of ocean depth data.  If you are looking for salinity and density measurements, then you should mention which ocean you are interested in, as it is dependent on location.  Also, don't expect "sonde-like" measurements in the ocean like they do in the atmosphere.

Answer (score 8):

There are several global products for temperature, salinity and pressure. The product that has been evolving for the longest is likely the World Ocean Database and World Ocean Atlas Series (https://www.nodc.noaa.gov/OC5/indprod.html) and their latest product WOA13 is very high quality (https://www.nodc.noaa.gov/OC5/woa13/). They also have the entire database of used observations.

A way to get a global database and also a way to visualize it and extract information is [HydroBase](http://www.whoi.edu/science/PO/hydrobase/php/index.php).

Another fabulous product that includes global information available monthly for the period 1900 to the present is provided by the [Met Office Haddley Centre](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/en4/). Their latest product is excellent.

If you are looking for model results, one option is to look at the global operational solutions as part of the GODAE initiative. A list of products is [here](http://www.godae.org/Ocean-products.html). Their model products include data assimilation, which helps the model from going to far from reality. The one I am most familiar with is [HYCOM](https://hycom.org/), which provides global data assimilative products at 1/12 degree resolution.

Answer (score 5):

You can find modeling data on the thermocline depth at the Global Change Master Directory at NASA.  Here is a link that allows you to download the data:
http://gcmd.nasa.gov/records/GCMD_IGOSS_NMC_PACMON_THERMOCLINE.html

> This data is from hindcast results derived from a model based ocean 
>   analysis system. Observed surface and subsurface ocean temperatures as 
>   well as satellite altimetry sea-level data from TOPEX/POSEIDON are 
>   assimilated into a Pacific basin ocean general circulation model. The 
>   model is forced with weekly mean NCEP operational atmospheric analyses 
>   of surface winds and heat fluxes.

Comment: No, no, no, no, no. I meant a simple table like they have on this page http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/531121/seawater/301668/Density-of-seawater-and-pressure

Comment: Maybe you should clarify your question, then